# MariaDB 10.2 Encrypted at rest log files not being written

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, master-master-replication

We're running MariaDB 10.2 with InnoDB tables that are encrypted at rest. I've also specified that the log files be encrypted at rest but they remain empty files. The tables seem to be encrypted just fine.

I'm hoping to get this database set up for replication with encrypted at rest log files.

Permissions all seem fine - can anyone think of a reason as to why the log files wont write?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my my.cnf

```
user=mysql

bind-address = 210.5.55.92
local-infile=0
max_connections=2000
max_allowed_packet=100M
skip-name-resolve

query_cache_type=0 
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_min_res_unit=512

key_buffer_size = 1G
sort_buffer_size=16M
read_buffer_size=16M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
thread_concurrency=0

default-storage-engine = InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2

innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend

thread_cache_size = 4

myisam_use_mmap=1
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M

symbolic-links=0

key_buffer_size=128M
sort_buffer_size=8M

expire-logs-days = 5
max-binlog-size  = 100M

open_files_limit=50000

table_open_cache=4096
table_definition_cache=4096

log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

general-log
general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/mysqld_queries.log
log-output=file

slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
long_query_time = 5
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1

plugin-load-add=file_key_management.so
file-key-management
file-key-management-filename = /var/lib/mysql/keys
innodb-encrypt-tables
innodb-encrypt-log
innodb-encryption-threads=4
```

Comment: Was the log being written before turning on encryption?  I see hints of 3 different logs; which logs are you asking about?

Comment: Good question. Actually when we moved to this server and version of MariaDB we set it up as encrypted at rest from the outset so I didn't pay enough attention.

All logs are nil files. Ultimately I'm interested in error logs and bin logs for replication though. Also I should add we've built a second identical server to host the slave DB and it has the same issue - I haven't activated bin logs on this one yet but did on the other one to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you turned on logbin and log_slave_updates?

Comment: I did on the other server to no effect. log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.err
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-replication.log
server_id=90
replicate-do-db=data

Comment: I don't see `server_id` in the my.cnf.  Are both Masters 10.2?

Comment: Sorry I see I'm confusing things here. Replication has been tested on machines that carry the same MariaDB 10.2 set up - but it wouldn't write bin-log files. I'm trying to get log files in general writing so I can move on and try to get bin-log files writing - and I'm assuming that fixing general logs will also solve the bin-log issue but if it doesn't I might have more information thanks to the other logs. So I'm showing minimum failing configs. The config above is not writing any log files and when I also add instructions to turn on bin-logs they don't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a bit of trial and error I've got all logs writing! I think the problem must have had to do with permissions as even though the log files were chown to mysql in the separate folder I planned to use - removing file designation from the config allowed logs to get written in the default folders. Sigh - thanks for your help!